# How do I map a text file's contents to a column in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that includes a "filename" column with values such as "train XXXXX.jpg" / "test XXXX.jpg".
I have another folder which contains text files named "train XXXXX boundingbox.txt" / "test XXXX boundingbox.txt"
How do I map the contents of each text file to the 'filename' column and create a new column called 'bb'?

Comment: You forgot to make it *specific* and to show your code attempt.

Comment: all filenames you provided are `.jpg`. Please edit your filenames. Also, are there any relations between `jpg` and `txt` filenames? If there is no relation, it is better to omit information about `jpg`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by computing the answer for a single row. Given filename, how do you get the list of numbers you want?

```
def get_bb(filename):
    base_filename = filename.removesuffix(".jpg")
    bb_filename = f'{base_filename}_boundingbox.txt'
    with open(bb_filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    bb = lines[0].rstrip().split(" ")
    bb = [float(b) for b in bb]
    return bb
```

Once you can do it for a single row, just use `.apply`

```
df = # load your filenames
df["bb"] = df["filename"].apply(get_bb)
```

Note: this will be slow because reading values from files is slow.

Comment: As you can see from the photos attached, I want the content of .txt files in front of the "filename" column. I have a folder where these .txt files are located and I want to read it from there and create a new column "bb" in front of "filename" column according to the names.

Comment: @Saurav That is exactly what the code I posted does. Please clarify your question is there is something missing.

Comment: In filename, I have to pass which parameter the filename, train_XXXXX_boundingbox.txt or the exact location of that file? Also, I have edited the question please go over that

Comment: @Saurav I'm still not seeing how my code doesn't accomplish the task you have set. Have you tried running it? You don't have to pass in the filename manually, the call to `.apply` does it for you.